# How to append a String to JSON String in java?

Tags: java, json, string

I am getting the data from the Zookeeper node like this

```
byte[] bytes = client.getData().forPath("/my/example/node1");
String ss = new String(bytes);
```

Here `ss` will have data like this which is a simple JSON String consisting of key value pair -

```
{"description":"Some Text", "machinename":"machineA", "ipaddress":"192.128.0.0"}
```

Now I want to append one more key value pair at the end to the above JSON String. This is the below key value pair I want to append -

```
"version":"v3"
```

So the final JSON String will look like this -

```
{"description":"Some Text", "machinename":"machineA", "ipaddress":"192.128.0.0", "version":"v3"}
```

What's the best and efficient way to do this?

Comment: As a general rule, don't.  You can do it, in limited cases, by doing the obvious string manipulations, but it's far better, in the general case, to deserialize the JSON, modify the resulting Map, and then reserialize the Map.

Comment: You need a JSON parser.

Comment: @HotLicks unless you can give a real reason, I don't buy that argument. Especially if he's just learning. Don't over engineer the problem.

Comment: Please, please PLEASE specify a charset when using the String constructor that takes an array of bytes, otherwise your code will break if the platform's default encoding is not what you expect. For JSON, you want UTF-8, so: new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Comment: @SLaks You are correct. Using string manipulation to produce (or, even worse, edit) JSON strings is a VERY bad idea in general.

Comment: @PNS would be lovely if you'd give even the slightest reason why. But yeah, lets just keep parroting the same answer!

Comment: @Zaphod42 - You don't buy my argument that there's a general rule with exceptions?  Which end of it don't you buy?  And which approach is "over-engineering"?

Comment: @Zaphod42 I have already told you of cases where string manipulation will fail. In general, you don't even know the JSON string before hand, so even attempting to do the manipulation is pointless. I will happily keep "parroting the same answer", because it is technically correct and the only one that has general applicability. Take the same friendly advise from all the others that have said the same, instead of insisting on a special case scenario. :-)

Comment: (For this particular case the use of string manipulation may be merited, since it avoids parsing the JSON into about a dozen objects, then reconstructing the JSON from those objects.  And for the uninitiated it's easier to understand.  I would not recommend the approach for any more complicated scenario, however.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a JSON Parser/Generator to parse your given JSON to a tree structure and then add your JSON field.

With Gson, that would look something like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(ss, JsonObject.class); // parse
jsonObject.addProperty("version", "v3"); // modify
System.out.println(jsonObject); // generate
```

prints

```
{"description":"Some Text","machinename":"machineA","ipaddress":"192.128.0.0","version":"v3"}
```

---

Will Zookeeper always return valid JSON or their custom format? Be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks. Yes Zookeeper will always return Valid JSON because in that format only (JSON document) I am storing the data inside the node. So when I am retrieving it, it gives me back the same JSON String which I have written earlier..

Comment: Jackson JSON library is widely used.

Comment: If he wants the most efficient way, this is overkill.

Comment: @DanielNuriyev Absolutely, Jackson's `ObjectMapper` has a corresponding method to give you an `ObjectNode`.

Comment: @Zaphod42 Efficiency doesn't only apply to how fast code executes. It has to do with writing the code, maintaining it, etc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, but your method creates an object from the full string only to deserialize it again; its wasteful if you can simply tack on a string. No part of basic java string manipulation is unmaintainable. You can put this method in a static class.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to JSON processing, string manipulation only works in special and simple cases. For the general case, a good JSON parser library should be used.

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is among the top of such libraries in terms of performance, efficiency, versatility and reliability, plus it is published under the commercial-friendly Apache 2.0 license.

Following is a simple implementation of the requested answer in [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String ss = "{\"description\":\"Some Text\", \"machinename\":\"machineA\", \"ipaddress\":\"192.128.0.0\"}";

    System.out.println("JSON string before: " + ss);

    try
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>)mapper.readValue(ss, Map.class);
        
        map.put("version", "v3");
        ss = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("JSON string after: " + ss);
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to use the ObjectMapper method that gives you a JsonNode, cast it to an ObjectNode and modify that.

Comment: Correct, I just opted for simplicity of explanation. I do prefer JsonNode in real world code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basic string manipulation. Insert your additional string before the final close brace }. Make sure to add a comma.

Json objects don't need to be ordered.

```
String json = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}";

String json2 = "\"version\":\"v3\"";

json2 = ',' + json2;

String json3 = json.substring(0,json.length()-1) + json2 + json.charAt(json.length()-1);
```

That should be the simplest, most efficient way, if that's all you need to do.

For additional reading on String manipulation,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Comment: Yes it will, and yes it is. I'm using ' instead of ", you should really use " and escape them, but otherwise this is correct.

Comment: Try to compile it. The error is tiny, but I want you to fix it.

Comment: Also, your substrings are off by 1. You're getting rid of a `"`. You wouldn't have that problem using a well built json generator.

Comment: Fine, done. If you want to help you should point out the problem. It was extremely minor though, I forgot length was a method and not a public field in java, SORRY.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because I changed something I shouldn't have, because you're being a dick. I had it mostly right the first time. Be constructive, don't mess with people. I'm not even the OP, I'm trying to help somebody, and you're messing with me instead of helping him.

Comment: I hope this exercise demonstrated how inefficient it was to generate your own JSON case by case.

Comment: It doesn't. It only demonstrated that I can't write Java from memory without testing the compiler because I've been writing C# lately. Get off your high horse, the code was almost flawless, and now its fine, If he had tested it he could have fixed that himself as soon as he saw the compiler errors, and now you can call this method all you want. It in no way is unmaintainable. If you think that, you have never worked on a large project before and you're overthinking something you heard a CS professor say.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44822/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-zaphod42)

Comment: @Zaphod42 Using string manipulation to produce (or, even worse, edit) JSON strings is a VERY bad idea in general. For simple cases it may work, but this does not make it good programming style. I have upvoted your answer because I consider negative marks as disrespectful (at least when an answer is decent), but what Sotirios said is correct and there is no need for tension. :-)

Comment: @PNS to produce the strings in general, yes, but if you're just appending a constant element, then that is not true.

Comment: Sure, but as you know programming is not about special cases and JSON processing in general should not be done via string processing. Even the slightest addition to a JSON string may break it, especially if it comes from user input that may have special characters, which need to be escaped. JSON manipulation should always happen via a JSON parser.